# pg-promise: Update existing connection with new password

Tags: pg-promise

I have a use case that many connections to the database are created dynamically using pg-promise. Sometimes I need to connect again to the same database and user however the password changed.

Is there a way to update an existing connection so I dont get the "WARNING: Creating a duplicate database object for the same connection."?

**Editing for better explanation:**

**Context**
I have a non-traditional application that is a node service that handles geospatial data aquisition in the software QGIS, with Postgres + PostGIS.

This application creates temporary users in the PostgreSQL server and manage permissions on the tables and columns based on the type of work the user needs to do.

**Code**

```js
    const dbs = {} //global variable that stores all connections
    
    const getConnection = async (user, password, server, port, dbname) => {
      const connString = `postgres://${user}:${password}@${server}:${port}/${dbname}`
      if (connString in dbs) {
        return dbs[connString]  //if connection already exists returns the connection
      }
    
      dbs[connString] = db.pgp(connString) //create new connection
      await dbs[connString] //tests if connections is correct
        .connect()
        .then(obj => {
          obj.done() // success, release connection;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          errorHandler.critical(e)
        })
    
      return dbs[connString]
    }
```

What I want is add another case, that if the connection already exists but the password changed it updates the existing connection password (or destroy it and create a new one).

Comment: Are you connecting manually? If so, then why? In any case, you should include the code example of what you are doing.

Comment: Edited for more explanation.

Comment: I tried several implementations myself, until I got the one working. Updated the answer with the final solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your case is that you are using password as part of the connection-string key, which isn't used within the library's unique-connection check, hence the side effect.

For the key, you need to use a unique connection string that does not contain the password. And when the request is made, you need to update the connection details.

Example below makes use of the connection object, not the connection string, because it is simpler that way. But if you want, you can use a connection string too, you would just need to generate a separate connection string, with the password, and update `$pool.options.connectionString`, not `$pool.options.password`.

```js
const dbs = {}; // global variable that stores all connections

const getConnection = async (user, password, host, port, database) => {
    const key = `${user}@${host}:${port}/${database}`; // unique connection key
    const cn = { host, port, database, user, password }; // actual connection
    let db; // resulting database object

    if (key in dbs) {
        db = dbs[key];
        db.$pool.options.password = password; // updating the password
    } else {
        db = pgp(cn); // creating new connection
        dbs[key] = db;

        await db // test if can connect
            .connect()
            .then(obj => {
               obj.done(); // success, release connection;
            })
            .catch(e => {
               errorHandler.critical(e);
               throw e;
            })
    }
   
    return db;
}
```